# Access data separated by New Line sent by POST method in flask

Tags: python, post, flask

I am creating a web application using Flask which will receive a certain number of URLs as a POST request through a .txt file where each URL is separated by a newline character ('\n').

For each URL I perform some operation like so

```
@app.route("/automated_testing", methods=['POST'])
def automated_testing():
    URL = # This will store individual URLs
    check_error, error_message = foo(URL) # foo() is insignificant, it justs checks if URL is of required format

    if check_error == False:
        return error_message

    else:
        someVariable = foo2(URL)

        final_result = {
            "key": URL,
            "value": someVariable
        }

        return jsonify(final_result)
```

**For each URL, I need to send a response with the key value pair as a JSON object (the response can also be an array of JSON objects of each URL).**

[EDIT 1]
**How do I get the individual URLs from the text file which is sent as the POST request?**

I tried using `request.get_data()` but I can't find a way to iterate through each URL in the file given.

Anyone know any way to achieve this?

---

This code works fine when there is a single POST request that is sent as params in which case I simply use

```
URL = request.args['url'] # url is the key for the param
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you can make a list with `split` function.

```
urls_string = "a.com\nb.net\nc.org"
urls_list = urls_string.split('\n')
print(urls_list)
```

output

```
['a.com', 'b.net', 'c.org']
```

Comment: Thanks for the response . However, my question was how will you get the list of URLs from the text file which is sent as a POST request in the first place.

Comment: I did go through this, however, I am still unable to figure how one is able to access the contents of the file that is uploaded? I would be happy if you could tell me how to do the same or direct me to a resource which shows how to access contents of a file that is received as a POST request.